# Add media attachment filter to custom wp.media frame

Tags: uploads, media-library

Using `wp.media` function to create custom uploader popup I can't find argument to show attachment filters.

```
if(typeof wp === 'undefined' || typeof wp.media === 'undefined') {
  return false;
}

var frame = wp.media({
   title: 'Custom title',
   multiple: false
});
```

My result:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make use of `filterable` property. To do that, you can extend the library and use that as a custom state.

```
// Create state
var myCustomState = wp.media.controller.Library.extend({
    defaults :  _.defaults({
        id: 'my-custom-state',
        title: 'Upload Image',
        allowLocalEdits: true,
        displaySettings: true,
        filterable: 'all', // This is the property you need. Accepts 'all', 'uploaded', or 'unattached'.
        displayUserSettings: true,
        multiple : false,
    }, wp.media.controller.Library.prototype.defaults )
});

//Setup media frame
frame = wp.media({
    button: {
        text: 'Select'
    },
    state: 'my-custom-state', // set the custom state as default state
    states: [
        new myCustomState() // add the state
    ]
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. I will send your bounty asap